# How to get parsed JSON back from api?

Tags: swift

This is my first time attempting to parse JSON from an api. I try to print the JSON but nothing is in the console. I am trying to get zipcodes in a radius from me.

This is how the JSON looks on the api's website[image: image of website]

My codable structs:

```
struct Zip: Codable {
    let Distance: Int
    let City: String
    let County: String
    let StateAbbr: String
    let ZipCode: String
}
struct Zips: Codable{
    var results: [Zip]
}
```

viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setView()
        let urlString = "https://zipcodedownload.com/Radius?firstzipcode=30316&radiuscoverage=10&format=json&pagenumber=1&key=9e2b15aa17f9434cbe62ddc32b40a521"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
               let resultsZips = try decoder.decode(Zips.self, from: data!)
                    print(resultsZips)
                }
                catch{
                     print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Distance` isn't an int

Comment: First: read more about async tasks. Second: Don't test your service code with a dummy UI. Third: be careful about the keys and types. and so on :)

Comment: And `catch` errors when you `try` something instead of ignoring them. So it will tell you the issue.

Comment: I added error handling and got this error back  **typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))**  @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: Read the debugDescription, it’s pretty clear. The root object is an array, note the square brackets in the JSON. You have to decode `[Zip].self`. The `Zips` struct is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are fetching an array of `Zip` (**not** a `results` key containing them). So first, you need to change the decoder:

```
decoder.decode([Zip].self, from: data!)
```

2. Sometimes `Distance` is not rounded. So you need to change its type to `Double`.
3. You will get the answer now but you should read the documentation of your API first, maybe some of them are optionals or maybe something else ‍♂️